# Does this Bedrock gold farm design also work in Java Edition?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition, version-differences

This is the farm:

It uses the block update system of the lava to trigger the portal on and off making zombie piglins to occasionally spawn and be washed down into a killing chamber. There could be two main issues that stop the farm from working in java which are observers observing different blocks, and zombie pigman spawning inside the portal and not on one side. The second problem is easy to fix by adding a couple of turtle eggs to lure them out but the Observing might not work and won't keep the portal up.
I haven't seen this kind of gold farm in java mode. Please help me with this problem.

Comment: Why don’t you try building this yourself in a Java Edition world to find out if it works?

Answer (score 2):

I have built it (I don't want to use glitches in my game) and yes it works, but not as shown.

You can't light up a portal with that lava setup, so you're stuck with piglins spawning naturally in the portal.

A zombie piglin will spawn on top of an obsidian block at the bottom of the portal frame if any of the portal blocks on that vertial received a random tick.

So, taller portals = higher chances of a piglin spawning, and larger portals = more chances of spawn.

Also, more portals = more chances.

Here is my setup:
[image]

I have 17 portals that are 23x23 plus another 14 that are 23x16.
They are gathering around a turtle egg I placed on top of a 2 high column of obsidian so that they would get close to my enraging platform, from where I throw an egg at them (and then I move to a killing pit).

This gives me a barely acceptable stream of 1 or 2 piglins per second.
I stupidly started this project underground, under my iron farm, so I can't easily expand it, but if you want, you could theoretically build more portals directly above so that you could increase your piglin spawning rate.

Expanded it can look like this:

Another possible layout is such:

And if you feel like bringing it to an extreme:

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, it does work on Java. However, it is VERY slow. the "zero-tick" method of flashing the portal on and off does not work on Java. Also, the pigmen can spawn on either side of the portal so you must account for that. Trident killers do not work on Java either.